# Send http headers from servlet to app in another environment

Tags: java, servlets, header, redirect

I need to send a request from a servlet to an application running in other environment (IIS) with certain information in custom headers.

I know redirecting doesn't send the headers and `getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url)` is to be used in the servlet's context only. Has anybody made this work in some other way? I was thinking in using `HttpURLConnection`, but would it finally redirect the browser to the targeted app ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to decide if you want the client to be redirected or not. If not, using HttpURLConnection (or apache http client) may be a good choice, making your servlet act as a non transparent proxy or gateway.

Comment: Actually I do want to do the redirection to the same page after the headers are sent; the question is how will the target asp know the redirection corresponds to the same request the headers were sent before (I can't touch the asp code that's expecting the headers).

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect from your servlet to the external server and keep the headers, and you can't forward the incoming request to other context.

What you could do, is to use the `HttpURLConnection` (or other http client library such as [HTTPClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/)) to make the request (with the custom headers you need) to the remote server and, once the operation is complete, redirect the user to the external site (customm headers are not set in this redirection).

This is a little tricky, if you elaborate your question (what do you really need to do) we can probably think about other alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX? You can send some JavaScript code  to the browser which sends a request to the ISS and handle (shows) its answer. It's possible [to set http headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#The_setRequestHeader_method) with [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) but it needs client side JavaScript coding and you have to find a way to send [cross domain requests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests).